# how to iterate for loop in robot frame work

Tags: robotframework

I Have a list of elements of size 200, and i need to get the style of each element. i am using for loop here to iterate over the elements list and trying to get the style of each element using get style .. But i am able to get only one first element's style from below code but i need to get style of all the 200 elements .. could some please help me to solve this ?

```
FOR    ${element}    IN    ${elements}
    ${style} =          get style       ${element}     key=display               
    log to console  ${style}                              
END
```

Comment: If your for loop works for one time, then you may getting only one element in the list. Try this line of code before running for loop, ${count}=    Get Element Count    ${locator}  and check count is giving as 200?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it looks like your accessing ${element} which is scalar variable, but to access a list you should use @{elements}. So this should work.

```
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements}
        ${style} =          get style       ${element}     key=display               
        log to console  ${style}  
    END
```

Comment: Thank you  @Manish Kumar, It works fine now